# Redux Form sync validation but get constant rules from server

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have read the documentation how to use sync validation.

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}

  ....

  if (!values.age) {
    errors.age = 'Required'
  } else if (isNaN(Number(values.age))) {
    errors.age = 'Must be a number'
  } else if (Number(values.age) < 18) {
    errors.age = 'Sorry, you must be at least 18 years old'
  }
  return errors
}
```

My need is I want the number '18' is retrieved from server? I need to setup all constants of the validation on server, and read it on page load only then used in this validation section.

Any help would be appreicated. thank you

Comment: I don't use redux-form, so I don't know if React is required, or not. If you're using React, use `componentWillMount()` and inside it `fetch('your/api/path')` the constants from the server. Once that's done, set the state inside of a `.then()`. Now, access that state as `this.state` inside your `validateConstants()` or inject it as a dependency `validateConstants(this.state.fetchedConstants)`. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand the question correctly.
why don't you initiate validate method on page load after you fetch all constants from server.

validateConstants.js

```
export const validateConstants = fetch()
```

validation.js

```
import { validateConstants } from 'validateConstants'
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}

  ....

  if (!values.age) {
    errors.age = 'Required'
  } else if (isNaN(Number(values.age))) {
    errors.age = 'Must be a number'
  } else if (Number(values.age) < validateConstants.age) {
    errors.age = 'Sorry, you must be at least 18 years old'
  }
  return errors
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is working, but I want validateConstants is imported from another file. so it can be used for another validation file (reusable). how can I do that? can you show me an example.

Comment: I updated my answer to export validateConstants for reuse